# Is this "dare" an auxiliary verb or a lexical one?

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs

I am studying auxiliary verbs, and I saw that "to dare" is a modal auxiliary. However, this sentence is somehow confusing:

- *He does not dare to interrupt.*

My question is: Is "to dare" a modal auxiliary or a lexical verb?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Oops! Thanks for pointing that out. I'll repost.

Comment: "Dare" can be either a lexical verb or an auxiliary one. In your example it can only be a lexical verb since it has the auxiliary "do" and a _to_-infinitival complement. Auxiliary "dare", by contrast, does not require "do" in non-affirmatives and takes a bare infinitival complement, as in "He dare not interrupt me".

Answer (score 2):

BillJ commented:

> "Dare" can be either a lexical verb or an auxiliary one. In your
> example
>
> - *He does not dare to interrupt*
>
> it can only be a lexical verb since it has the auxiliary "do" and a
> to-infinitival complement. Auxiliary "dare", by contrast, does not
> require "do" in non-affirmatives and takes a bare infinitival
> complement, as in
>
> - *He dare not interrupt me.*

Comment: Also note that as an auxiliary it is "he dare" not "he dares".

Comment: @StuartF Why do you claim that? In *He ha**s** not finished*, the verb *has* is an auxiliary verb. And arguably in *He dares not interrupt me*, the verb *dare* must be an auxiliary, as it uses *not* to negate it and doesn't require *do*-support. And examples like that are found all over the place!